# Rigorous scaling limit for Navier-Stokes and Boltzmann equation

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

In the now 35 years old survey paper ''[Kinetic equations from Hamiltonian dynamics](http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.52.569)'', Herbert Spohn mentions two important unsolved problems in mathematical physics: On p.571 the hydrodynamic limit, and on p.603 the derivation of the nonlinear Boltzmann equation from quantum mechanics.

Where can I find the current state of affairs? In particular, are there now rigorous derivations of the Navier-Stokes equations and/or the Boltzmann equations from either nonrelativistic many-particle quantum mechanics or quantum field theory? If yes, under which assumptions?

Answer (score 7):

[The Boltzmann Equation from Quantum Field Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1301)

> We show from first principles the emergence of classical Boltzmann
>   equations from relativistic nonequilibrium quantum field theory as
>   described by the Kadanoff-Baym equations. Our method applies to a
>   generic quantum field, coupled to a collection of background fields
>   and sources, in a homogeneous and isotropic spacetime. We show that the system follows a generalized Boltzmann equation whenever the WKB approximation holds. The generalized Boltzmann equation, which includes off-shell transport, is valid far from equilibrium and in a time dependent background, such as the expanding universe.